# Trying to pass user generated variable to an external command

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I have a bash script that is asking a user for input, then passes that variable to a find command.  I've tried quoting/escaping the variable every way I know, but it keeps failing.

```
read -p "Please enter the directory # to check: " MYDIR
count=`/usr/bin/find /path/to/$MYDIR -name *.txt -mmin -60 | wc -l`
if [ $count != 0 ]
    then 
         echo "There have been $count txt files created in $MYDIR in the last hour"
    else 
         echo "There have been no txt files created in the last hour in $MYDIR "
    fi
```

When running, I get this:

```
Please enter the directory # to check: temp_dir

/usr/bin/find: paths must precede expression
Usage: /usr/bin/find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
There have been no txt files created in the last hour in temp_dir
```

Comment: Use single or double quotes around *.txt ie. `"*.txt"` to prevent it getting interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must quote the pattern in `-name` option:

```
count="$(/usr/bin/find /path/to/$MYDIR -name '*.txt' -mmin -60 | wc -l)"
```

If you don't use the quote, so the shell will expand the pattern. Your command become:

```
/usr/bin/find "/path/to/$MYDIR" -name file1.txt file2.txt ... -mmin -60 | wc -l
```

You feed all files, which has name end with `.txt` to `-name` option. This causes syntax error.

Comment: Ah...so I was trying to quote the wrong problem child... thanks!